# How can I detect the mouse polling rate with my script?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to figure out how to get the polling rate of a mouse using JavaScript. I've searched most of SO questions and none of them seem to direct me in the right path. While I was doing my research I came across [this site](https://zowie.benq.com/en/support/mouse-rate-checker.html), which is exactly what i was looking for, however I am not sure how they achieved this. Can someone help me out figure this out?

Digging around a bit more in the website I was able to find the following code, however I can't understand it completely. Can someone shed some light on this?
How can I replicate this without stealing code? I want to be able to understand this so that I can try and write my own.

```
var fps = 4;
var count = 0;
var tick = 0;
var total = 0;
var tmr = null;
var testExp = new RegExp('Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|' + 'BlackBerry|Windows Phone|' + 'Opera Mini|IEMobile|Mobile', 'i');
var isDesktop = !(testExp['test'](navigator['userAgent']));
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i ['test'](navigator['userAgent']);
var isIE = false || !!document['documentMode'];
var body = document['querySelector']('body');
var divCanvas = document['createElement']('DIV');
var current = document['createElement']('TEXTAREA');
var average = document['createElement']('P');
var canvas;
var ctx;
body['appendChild'](divCanvas);
body['appendChild'](average);
current['cols'] = '10';
current['rows'] = '20';
current['readOnly'] = true;
current['style']['fontSize'] = '14px';
current['style']['position'] = 'absolute';
current['style']['top'] = '10px';
current['style']['right'] = '20px';
current['style']['color'] = 'white';
current['style']['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
average['style']['position'] = 'absolute';
average['style']['top'] = '190px';
average['style']['left'] = '35%';
average['style']['width'] = '400px';
average['style']['color'] = '#CC0040';
average['style']['backgroundColor'] = 'black';

function updateCount() {
    tick++;
    total += count;
    var _0x1d38x11 = document['createTextNode'](count * fps + ' Hz\x0A');
    current['appendChild'](_0x1d38x11);
    current['scrollTop'] = current['scrollHeight'];
    var _0x1d38x12 = canvas['width'] / 2 - 200;
    ctx['fillStyle'] = 'black';
    ctx['fillRect'](_0x1d38x12, 190, 400, 60);
    var _0x1d38x13 = 'Average: ';
    var _0x1d38x14 = Math['ceil'](fps * total / tick);
    var _0x1d38x15 = ' Hz';
    ctx['textAlign'] = 'left';
    ctx['font'] = '40px Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif';
    ctx['fillStyle'] = 'white';
    ctx['fillText'](_0x1d38x13, _0x1d38x12, 240);
    var _0x1d38x16 = ctx['measureText'](_0x1d38x13);
    ctx['font'] = '60px Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif';
    ctx['fillStyle'] = '#CC0040';
    var _0x1d38x17 = ctx['measureText'](_0x1d38x14);
    ctx['fillText'](_0x1d38x14, _0x1d38x12 + _0x1d38x16['width'], 240);
    ctx['font'] = '40px Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif';
    ctx['fillStyle'] = 'white';
    ctx['fillText']('Hz', _0x1d38x12 + _0x1d38x16['width'] + _0x1d38x17['width'], 240);
    count = 0;
    if (tick > 3 * fps) {
        tick = 0;
        total = 0
    }
}

function degToRad(_0x1d38x19) { var _0x1d38x1a = Math['PI'] / 180 * _0x1d38x19; return _0x1d38x1a }

function eventWindowLoaded() { canvasDraw() }
var x = 50;
var y = 50;

function canvasDraw() {
    if (x > canvas['clientWidth'] + 20) { x = 0 };
    if (y > canvas['clientHeight'] + 20) { y = 0 };
    if (x < -20) { x = canvas['clientWidth'] };
    if (y < -20) { y = canvas['clientHeight'] };
    ctx['fillStyle'] = 'white';
    ctx['textAlign'] = 'center';
    ctx['font'] = '60px Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif';
    ctx['fillText']('Mouse Rate Checker', canvas['width'] / 2, 100);
    ctx['font'] = '40px Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif';
    ctx['fillText']('Please click and move your mouse to start.', canvas['width'] / 2, 160)
}

function lockChangeAlert() {
    count = 0;
    tick = 0;
    total = 0;
    if (document['pointerLockElement'] === canvas || document['mozPointerLockElement'] === canvas) {
        document['addEventListener']('mousemove', canvasLoopMm, false);
        if (tmr) { clearInterval(tmr) };
        tmr = setInterval(updateCount, 1000 / fps)
    } else {
        document['removeEventListener']('mousemove', canvasLoopMm, false);
        clearInterval(tmr);
        tmr = null
    }
}

function canvasLoop(_0x1d38x21) {
    var _0x1d38x22 = _0x1d38x21['movementX'] || _0x1d38x21['mozMovementX'] || 0;
    var _0x1d38x23 = _0x1d38x21['movementY'] || _0x1d38x21['mozMovementY'] || 0;
    x += _0x1d38x22;
    y += _0x1d38x23
}

function canvasLoopMm(_0x1d38x25) {
    var _0x1d38x26 = 'getCoalescedEvents' in _0x1d38x25 ? _0x1d38x25['getCoalescedEvents']() : [_0x1d38x25];
    for (e in _0x1d38x26) {
        canvasLoop(e);
        count++
    }
}

function divLoopMm(_0x1d38x21) { count++ }
var w = window['innerWidth'] || document['documentElement']['clientWidth'] || document['body']['clientWidth'];
var h = window['innerHeight'] || document['documentElement']['clientHeight'] || document['body']['clientHeight'];
if (!isDesktop) {
    console['log']('DOES NOT SUPPORT MOBILE DEVICES');
    var h1 = document['createElement']('H1');
    h1['innerHTML'] = 'Mouse Rate Checker';
    divCanvas['appendChild'](h1);
    average['innerHTML'] = 'Can\'t be used on mobile devices'
} else {
    if (isSafari || isIE) {
        divCanvas['setAttribute']('style', 'width:' + w + 'px');
        divCanvas['setAttribute']('style', 'height:' + h + 'px');
        var h1 = document['createElement']('H1');
        h1['innerHTML'] = 'Mouse Rate Checker';
        divCanvas['appendChild'](h1);
        average['innerHTML'] = 'Does not support IE or Safari.'
    } else {
        body['appendChild'](current);
        window['addEventListener']('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);
        canvas = document['createElement']('CANVAS');
        divCanvas['appendChild'](canvas);
        ctx = canvas['getContext']('2d');
        canvas['setAttribute']('width', w);
        canvas['setAttribute']('height', h);
        window['onclick'] = function () {
            count = 0;
            tick = 0;
            total = 0;
            if (tmr) {
                clearInterval(tmr);
                document['removeEventListener']('pointermove', canvasLoopMm);
                tmr = null
            } else {
                document['addEventListener']('pointermove', canvasLoopMm);
                if (tmr) { clearInterval(tmr) };
                tmr = setInterval(updateCount, 1000 / fps)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i made a quick example of how you could do this:

```
<div id="frequency"></div>
<script>
var frequency = 0;
var pos;
var lasttime = 0;
var mousePos = {};
mousePos.x = 0;
mousePos.y = 0;
document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
setInterval(getMousePosition, 1); // setInterval repeats every X ms
function handleMouseMove(event) {
    var dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;
    event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
    mousePos = {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
    };
}
function getMousePosition() {
    var newpos = mousePos.x+'_'+mousePos.y;
    if (pos != newpos) {
        var newtime = window.performance.now();
        var elapsed_time = newtime-lasttime;
        var newfrequency = parseInt(1000/elapsed_time);
        if(newfrequency > frequency){
            frequency = newfrequency;
            document.getElementById('frequency').innerHTML = frequency+'hz';
        }
        pos = newpos;
        lasttime = newtime;
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically, it reads the mouse position every 1ms, and if the position is changed, it checks the time elapsed since the last change. The goal is to get how many times per seconds (hz) the position is read. Now in the link you provided they added an average, but it does not really mean anything... The only accurate value you can get from this is the one you will get when moving the mouse quicker than it's frequency. In my case, when i use this script and move quickly in the screen, i get 125hz, which means that it always takes at least 8ms for the value to change even if i'm constantly moving the mouse.

Comment: *"it reads the mouse position every 1ms"* No, it reads the mouse position [*no more frequently*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) than once every millisecond, subject to throttling and processing delays. And `Date.now()` is [intentionally not very precise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Reduced_time_precision).

Comment: @Francois thank you for your code, i tried it but it seems to not work correctly. i have a mouse that is running at 1000hz and when i test it in the website that i link i get around 950hz but when i tried your code i seem to be getting random numbers.

Comment: Updated original question with additional information

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder since the goal is to catch the highest frequency, i updated my code. Can you try this one and tell me what you get ?

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé i tried it but this time it shows me some very high number like 2450Hz. The basic idea is i want to know what is the polling rate of the mouse when a user moves his mouse inside a given div. similar to the website.

Comment: So i got the thing working as the website. they used pointerEvents getCoalescedEvents to get the the current move tick and divide it by fps. however when i do it with the console open i get the correct value but when i do it normally the browser uses the monitor's refresh rate to cap the mouse events at 60fps

Comment: @TheConfusedCoder i see... what do you want to achieve with this in the end ? do you need to find the real frequency of the user mouse ? Because i read that there is not a lot of different possibilities. mostly 125, 250, 500, 100, 2000 or something like that, so using this kind of method it would be fairly easy to determine which one it is...

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé 1000hz is the most a mouse can go and i already got it working similar to the site. i use the same pointer events and the same logic to divide the count based on the fps given in their formula and get it to work.